# How do I vertically center the text in an input element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a custom design for an input element, which requires me to use the font Akko Pro Light. However, when I do so, the text strangely aligns vertically to the top of the line. This is true for the placeholder text as well as any text I actually write into the element.

[image: Input element with incorrectly aligned text]

While testing, other fonts do not produce the same problem.

Comment: which CSS style have you applied to it? Please add your code here to debug it.

Comment: Maybe something with `vertical-align` or a `padding` problem ... but without code that's just guessing. Please prepar the relevant piece of code (html/css) so it is possible to help you.

Comment: Please write code-examples for a better understanding and take care of different browsers. Some do not want you to change input elements (...)

Comment: Did you try padding ? ... put your code in post to get more help

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, everyone. I'd love to add the code but it wont let me... I will do so in the future.

Looks like it was simply the font itself coming with whitespace at the bottom for some strange reason...

Answer (score 0):

try using justify-content: center; in css along with text-align: center; unfortunately without seeing the code it is hard to know what you are doing to find what is happening

Comment: Good tip, thank you!

And yes, I'll have to put in code next time. Still getting the hang of Stack Overflow... ;)

Comment: No problem! I get it :)

Answer (score -1):

Make a `padding` to create a space arround and `line-height`. Awoid non-standard fonts, it reduces the permonance of your site.

```css
#field1 {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
field: <input type="text" value="field1" id="field1" /><br />
```

Comment: The op said that the font aligned itself vertically

Comment: if so, try increase the font-size

Comment: All good points, and that's probably what I'll be doing. Apparently this font strangely enough has that whitespace on the bottom.